# Artin reciprocity

Tags: class-field-theory

The *Artin reciprocity* says that if $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is a finite abelian extension with defining modulus $m$, then the sequence of groups

$$
1\to I_{L,m}\to (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^\times\to Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})\to 1
$$

is exact.

I do not quite see why this is a substantial theorem, because it is simply saying that the Artin map (the third arrow) is surjective; $I_{L,m}$ is defined as the kernel of the Artin map, so the second arrow being injective is trivial. Also, why is it called "reciprocity"? Does this theorem have any interesting consequences?

Comment: Well it's supposed to generalize quadratic reciprocity and cubic reciprocity...

Comment: @Kenny Lau: How does it generalize them?

Comment: The most substantive part is that there **is** a defining modulus.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown: Isn't that the Kronecker-Weber theorem, rather than Artin reciprocity?